# Nested @Transactional and exceptions

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions, transactional

i want to perform some operations and store it's result (success or failure) in db.

```java
@Service
public MyService {

    @Transactional
    public void myOperation() {
        try {
           otherService.doDatabaseOperationThatMayFail();
           repository.writeSuccess()
        } catch (Exception e) {
          repository.writeFailure()
        }
    }
}
```

But if `otherService.doDatabaseOperationThatMayFail()` itself is marked as `@Transactional`or uses such components and any of those methods throws an exception then the whole transaction is marked for rollback. I can't remove `@Transactional` from all services used by `MyService`. So how can I store the failure info in my database?

Comment: With your current solution you cannot and never will be able to do it. Instead you will have to have a separate transaction for the success/failure write. Either annotate it with `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` or use a `TransactionTemplate` to control a new transaction. Depending on your needs you could (and I probably would do that) create an Aspect that contains this logic and executes in another transaction (and that direct makes it reusable instead of you having to copy-paste code).